# Getting OS and data onto a USB drive in order to switch to USB booting

Tags: usb, boot, retropie

I have a Retropie setup running on a Pi2 B. Currently the OS is on the MicroSD card from which the Pi boots. The games themselves are on a USB stick and are read from there when playing.

I’m planning to set up booting from USB when I upgrade to a Pi4. I’d like to put the entire OS and all the games onto a USB stick. I have made changes to the various configurations (added shutdown/reboot button, made EmulationStation and Retropie changes, etc.) and want to be sure those carry over.

I assume I can’t just copy the MicroSD card to a USB stick then add the games to the proper folders. Can anyone please help me determine what steps to take to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you planning on booting from USB on a pi 2? anyway, you can just copy the whole microSD (both partitions) onto a USB stick - I've never used retro pi so not sure how much of raspberry pi OS is in there, but there's a sd card copier (or something like that) that will do the copying for you. But I re-iterate, how will you make the Pi 2 boot from USB?

Comment: @Bravo I’d have sworn I mentioned upgrading to Pi4 but I didn’t. That edit has now been made, thanks.

Comment: fair enough - that makes more sense then - anyway, you can use something like belana etcher (I think it's called that) to read the whole SD card, then write it on to a USB stick

Comment: So apparently I can just copy it over. Good to know.

Comment: I've done it - though if you can use SD Copier (it's called something like that) it's better to do so

Comment: There's a script to make this all automatic https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=196778

Answer (score 0):

No you can not "just copy it over".

It also depends what "just copy it over" means.

I haven't used Retropie but assuming it uses Raspberry Pi OS as a base you may need to make a couple of changes. (This assumes that Retropie even runs on a Pi4).

If you made an installable image and imaged to the USB drive it should work.

`/boot/cmdline.txt` should contain something like:-

```
console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=39a147aa-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

The PARTUUID=39a147aa-02 identifies the drive and which partition contains the root, which must agree with the `label-id` of the drive and the entries in `etc/fstab`.

The following is a script I use to check consistency.

```
#! /bin/sh
# 2021-02-10

#   Check consistency of Disk identifier in cmdline.txt /etc/fstab

# Determine Disk identifier
DISKID=$(sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0 | awk '/Disk identifier/ {print $3};' | sed 's/0x//')

# Use sed to delete all BEFORE PARTUUID= and all AFTER -0  in /boot/cmdline.txt
ROOTPART=$(sed -e 's/^.*PARTUUID=//' -e 's/-0.*$'// /boot/cmdline.txt)
echo "Disk ID\t\t"$DISKID
echo "root PARTUUID\t"$ROOTPART

# find first PARTUUID ext4 in /etc/fstab
EXISTFSTABPART=$(awk '/PARTUUID.*ext4/ {print $1; exit};' /etc/fstab | sed -e 's/^.*PARTUUID=//' -e 's/-0.*$'//)

echo "Existing fstab\t"$EXISTFSTABPART

if [ $DISKID = $EXISTFSTABPART ]; then
    echo "Looks OK!"
# else
fi
```

The following is a similar script to check a mounted SD, which should work for a USB drive, but have not tried.

```
#! /bin/bash
# 2020-03-09
# 2021-02-10
# Check consistency of Partition ID on mounted SD Card

BOOT_MOUNT='/mnt/SDA1'
ROOT_MOUNT='/mnt/SDA2'

# Check/create Mount Points
if [ ! -e $BOOT_MOUNT ]; then
    mkdir $BOOT_MOUNT
fi
if [ ! -e $ROOT_MOUNT ]; then
    mkdir $ROOT_MOUNT
fi
    echo "mounts " $BOOT_MOUNT  $ROOT_MOUNT
if [ -e /dev/sda ]; then
    SD1='/dev/sda1'
    SD2='/dev/sda2'
    SD='/dev/sda'
else
    SD1='/dev/sdb1'
    SD2='/dev/sdb2'
    SD='/dev/sdb'
fi
echo $SD

# Mount Partitions
if ! $(mountpoint -q $BOOT_MOUNT); then
    sudo mount $SD1 $BOOT_MOUNT # mount partition containing boot files
fi
if ! $(mountpoint -q $ROOT_MOUNT); then
    sudo mount $SD2 $ROOT_MOUNT # mount root partition containing OS files
fi


# Determine Disk identifier of SD Card
DISKID=$(sudo fdisk -l $SD | awk '/Disk identifier/ {print $3};' | sed 's/0x//')

# Use sed to delete all BEFORE PARTUUID= and all AFTER -0  in $BOOT_MOUNT/cmdline.txt
ROOTPART=$(sed -e 's/^.*PARTUUID=//' -e 's/-0.*$'// $BOOT_MOUNT/cmdline.txt)

echo -e "Disk ID\t\t"$DISKID
echo -e "root PARTUUID\t"$ROOTPART

# find first PARTUUID ext4 in $ROOT_MOUNT/etc/fstab
EXISTFSTABPART=$(awk '/PARTUUID.*ext4/ {print $1; exit};' $ROOT_MOUNT/etc/fstab | sed -e 's/^.*PARTUUID=//' -e 's/-0.*$'//)

echo -e "Existing fstab\t"$EXISTFSTABPART

if [ $DISKID = $EXISTFSTABPART ]; then
    echo "Looks OK!"
else
    echo "Partition ID mismatch!"
    # Edit cmdline.txt & fstab to new DISKID & create new temporary files
    sed -e "s/$ROOTPART/$DISKID/" $BOOT_MOUNT/cmdline.txt > cmdline.txt.new
    sed -e "s/$ROOTPART/$DISKID/" $ROOT_MOUNT/etc/fstab > fstab.new
    echo -n "Set DiskID to ${DISKID} on $SD (y/n)? "
    while read -r -n 1 -s answer; do
        if [[ "${answer}" = [yY] ]]; then
          echo "Change"
          sudo cp -v cmdline.txt.new $BOOT_MOUNT/cmdline.txt
          sudo cp -v fstab.new $ROOT_MOUNT/etc/fstab
          break
        else
          echo "Aborted"
          exit
        fi
    done
fi
```